# Code igniter email functionality

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I am using codeigniter for my web application and i use the codeigniter's email functionality to send email. But I occurred the following error when i try to send the email.

*Unable to find the socket transport "ssl" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP*

This is the code i used to gain the functionality.

```
$config['protocol'] = "smtp";
    $config['smtp_host'] = "ssl://smtp.googlemail.com";
    $config['smtp_port'] = 465;
    $config['smtp_user'] = "xxxx@gmail.com";
    $config['smtp_pass'] = "xxxxxx";

    $this->load->library('email');
    $this->email->initialize($config);
    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

    $this->email->from('xxxx@gmail.com','Sample');
    $this->email->to('xxxxx@gmail.com');
    $this->email->subject('temperary Email');
    $this->email->message('This is a sample message');

    if ($this->email->send()) {
        echo 'Your email was sent, dude.';
    } else {
        show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
    }
```

What is wrong with this?

Thanks..

Comment: The error message gives you a good place to start. Try looking at confirming you do have SSL on the machine, and that it's enabled in PHP.

Comment: Your code is OK, but your php configuration doesn't know about the `ssl://` protocol. Make sure it's enabled.

Comment: As the message said...do you enabled `extension=php_openssl.dll` in your php.ini? What platform are you on?

Comment: Thanks guys. I had to configure the php.ini and enable the ssl module for apache. Then it worked like a mirakle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open ssl should be enabled.

have a look here http://www.devcha.com/2010/01/php-fsockopen-unable-to-connect-ssl.html

Or you can load the parameter in array:

```
    $config = Array(
    'protocol' => 'smtp',
    'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
    'smtp_port' => 465,
    'smtp_user' => 'xxx',
    'smtp_pass' => 'xxx',
    'mailtype'  => 'html', 
    'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1'
);
$this->load->library('email', $config);
$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

// Set to, from, message, etc.

$result = $this->email->send();
```

This works for me

Comment: Thanks shuvo. I had to configure the php.ini and enable the apache ssl module. Then it worked

Answer (score 0):

I had some "crazy" problems using the CI´s default email library to send emails through SSL/TLS authenticated SMTP servers. I ended up using PHPMailer instead.